# Selected tab allowed to change even though field invalid

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

**Here's my situation:** I have a `TabControl` with two `TabPage's` (`tabPage1` & `tabPage2`). `tabPage2` has a custom user control that I've created (because it's used in multiple forms) which contains a `TextBox` on it that has some custom validation attached to it via the `Validating` event of the custom user control. If I have `tabPage2` selected and have entered invalid data into the textbox and try to leave the textbox, validation works as it should, my custom event handler is run and things operate as I tell them to. However, if (in this same scenario) I switch to `tabPage1` from `tabPage2` instead of just leaving the textbox, it is allowed to switch to `tabPage1`. My textbox is then validated twice. Also, I can't control anything else on the form because I give the textbox the focus if it is found to be invalid but I can't see the textbox to be able to put any valid data in it! (I hope that all made sense. Don't be afraid to ask me to clarify if needed.)

**Here's my question:** How can I stop the tabs from switching when a field is found to be invalid; thus, also resolving the issue of the validation being run twice?

**Here's my code:** (This method is contained in the custom user control mentioned.)

```
private void OnValidatingUserControl(object sender, CancelEventArgs args)
{
  if (IsTextBoxInvalid())
  {
    args.Cancel = true;
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid data in text box!!!", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

    this.textBox.Focus();
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably you need to find the `BeforeChangeTab` (or similar name) event, and there, invoke textbox validation, before telling the tabs if they can change or not.

Comment: I could not find that event, so, it will be the `SelectedIndexChanged`, and if validation is false, return to the textbox tab.

Comment: @Daniel Good suggestion, however, the validation takes place in a seperate User Control that I've create. So, the user control doesn't really have any knowledge of the `TabPage` which it resides on. I did try checking if the `Parent` of the user control is a `TabPage` and if so then select the `TabPage`, then give my textbox focus...but this wouldn't work if the `TabPage` contained a `Panel` which contained the user control. Also, validation is still run twice so I see the message box twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by doing the following:

```
tabCtrl.CausesValidation = false;
tabPage1.CausesValidation = false;
tabPage2.CausesValidation = false;
userCtrl.CausesValidation = false;
```

I really don't care if the tabs are switched as long as the user can't leave the form without it validating. So, this solution allows for switching tabs but still allows for normal validation. I also redid my OnValidatingTextBox code so that the tab would be selected before focus is given to the field in error:

```
private void OnValidatingUserControlPanel(object sender, CancelEventArgs args)
{
  if (IsTextBoxInvalid())
  {
    args.Cancel = true;
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid data in text box!!!", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

    this.GiveFocusToControlIfTabPage(this.Parent);
    this.textBox.Focus();
  }
}

private void GiveFocusToControlIfTabPage(Control ctrl)
{
  if (ctrl== null)
  {
    return;
  }
  if (ctrl is TabPage)
  {
    TabPage tabPage = (TabPage)ctrl;
    ((TabControl)tabPage.Parent).SelectedTab = tabPage;
    return;
  }
  this.GiveFocusToControlIfTabPage(ctrl.Parent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you have found the solution of your problem, if you will need to prevent the user to change the tabs, you can create a global variable

```
static class GlobalVariables
{
    public static bool UserControlValidationError = false;
}
```

change its state in the OnValidatingUserControl

```
private void OnValidatingUserControl(object sender, CancelEventArgs args)
{
  if (IsTextBoxInvalid())
  {
    args.Cancel = true;
    GlobalVariables.UserControlValidationError = true;
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid data in text box!!!", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

    this.textBox.Focus();
  }
  else
  {
    GlobalVariables.UserControlValidationError = false;
  }
}
```

and prevent the tabs to change like this

```
private void tabCtrl_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = GlobalVariables.UserControlValidationError;
}
```